# Querying database schema of SQL Server DB via ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, unixodbc

Is there a generic way to retrieve a database schema using ODBC that works across databases?

If not, what is the easiest way to do this when the database server is MS SQL Server?

I am working with unixodbc, from Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query against the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) views. Beautiful thing about using information schema is that it's a standard so it should be portable to any database that has implemented the standard.

e.g.
`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC`

The standard is the [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) Starts at page 535

Comment: SQL-92, updated answer with link. Somewhat decently adopted from my world-view

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this was standardized.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list of the schema's in the database, you can use the wildcard in the SQLTables call

SQLTables( stmt, NULL, 0, "%", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, 0 );

Or something close to that.