# Connect to DB2/400 from RoR on Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, db2-400

I am trying to connect to DB/2 on an iSeries i5 AS/400 from Ruby on Rails running on Linux.

When I connect to port 446 with the IBM_DB adapter, I get a licensing error, so I started looking at ODBC.

When I use the iSeries ODBC driver along with unixodbc, iSQL works fine, I can use irb to execute SQL commands, but when I try to

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

I get: "odbc_adapter.rb:30:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`require_library_or_gem' for main:Object (NoMethodError)"

Using the IBM_DB adapter would be ideal, but it appears that it requires an additional license when talking to an i5.

Should I be able to rake db:schema:dump using the ODBC connection to the i5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stack overflow question may help...

[Querying database schema of SQL Server DB via ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955718/querying-database-schema-of-sql-server-db-via-odbc)

It suggests that you can extract the schema with...

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with querying the schema via ODBC!  Can anyone confirm that I need a license to use IBM_DB from Ruby on Rails on Linux to DB2/400?